# Why does JUnit5 fail when testing for a REST Delete functionality?

Tags: java, spring, junit

I am making a REST Crud Application and testing its functionalities using JUnit5

All of the other Create, Read, Update are working, however my Delete test fails.

The following is the method from the controller:

```
@DeleteMapping("/{userId}")
public ResponseEntity<?> delete(@PathVariable("userId") int userId) {

    if (userId < 0 || userId >= usersList.size()) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body("User not found.");
    }

    usersList.remove(userId);
    
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body("User Deleted Successfully");
}
```

The following is the Test which fails

```
@Test
void deleteUserTest() {
    String url = "http://localhost:" + port + "/users";
    
    int gameId = 0;

    String deleteUrl = url + "/" + userId;
    restTemplate.delete(deleteUrl);

    // Verify the user is deleted
    ResponseEntity<User> getResponse = restTemplate.getForEntity(url + "/" + userId, User.class);
    assertEquals(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, getResponse.getStatusCode());
}
```

And the output of this testing is:
`AssertionFailedError:  Expected :404 NOT_FOUND Actual   :405 METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED`

I tried changing the Not Found status to anything else, however the Test always gives me Actual: Method not allowed. It should return that the user is *not found* after deleting it. (btw I created some users before running the test and test that there are 3-4 users).

Comment: Your method is for DELETE you are issuing a GET.